# Как вывести цифры числа на экран

Tags: java

Нужно создать программу, которая выводит через пробел цифры числа, введенного с клавиатуры. Например, для `4561` нужно вывести `4 5 6 1`.

При этом разрешается использовать `while`, `for`, `do while` и арифметические действия. Не разрешается использовать строковые операции (например, `toString`).

В обратном порядке получилось сделать при помощи этого алгоритма:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = s.nextInt();
int b = 0;
int c;
while (a != 0) {
    c = a % 10;
    b = b * 10 + c;
    a = a / 10;
    System.out.print(b % 10 + " ");
}
```

Как вывести цифры в прямом порядке с учетом заданных ограничений?

Comment: `1 2 3 4 5 6` это для какого входного значения?

Comment: Очень интересно вы рассказываете! А вопрос в чём?

Comment: a.toString() - и откусывай с начала по одному символу...

Comment: Вопрос в том что бы вывести число через пробел например 4561 надо вывести 4 5 6 1

Comment: while, for, do while и арифметические действия. а toString() я не могу использовать

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что в представленном алгоритме переменная `b` бесполезна от слова "полностью": на экран достаточно было выводить `c`.

Comment: На входе любое число введенное с клавиатуры

Comment: С помощью WHILE посчитай количество цифр. А затем в цикле выделяй i-ю цифирь двойным делением.

Comment: Извините,а что значит "в цикле выделяй i-ю цифирь двойным делением"Как это сделать?@Akina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с предварительным подсчетом количества цифр. Подсчет количества здесь условный, потому что по факту высчитывается с какого делителя (`divider`) начинать делить число.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = s.nextInt();
int divider = 1;
while (divider <= a)
{
    divider *= 10;
}
divider /= 10;
while (divider > 0)
{
    int digit = a / divider;
    a -= digit * divider;
    System.out.print(digit + " ");
    divider /= 10;
}
```

Этот вариант работает только с положительными числами.

---

Вариант без предварительного подсчета количества пользователя и с перебором всех вариантов делителя:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = s.nextInt();
boolean gotFirstDigit = false;
for (int divider = 1000 * 1000 * 1000; divider > 0; divider /= 10)
{
    int digit = a / divider;
    if (!gotFirstDigit)
    {
        gotFirstDigit = (digit != 0);
    }
    if (gotFirstDigit)
    {
        a -= digit * divider;
        System.out.print(digit + " ");
    }
}
```

Этот вариант также работает только с положительными числами.

---

Оба варианта используют один и тот же способ для получения цифр: целая часть от деления числа на заданный делитель.

---

Для обработки нуля и отрицательных чисел можно добавить такой код:

```
int a = s.nextInt();
if (a == 0)
{
    System.out.print(0);
    return;
}
if (a < 0)
{
    System.out.print("- ");
    a *= -1;
}
```

Единственное ограничение: данный код не будет работать для `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (`-2147483648`).

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием метода toCharArray():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner number = new Scanner (System.in); // вводим число в консоли
    char [] numeral = number.nextLine().toCharArray(); // из введенного числа создаем массив символов
    for (char x:numeral) 
    System.out.print(x + " "); // каждый элемент массива выводим в консоль через пробел

    // развернуто:
    Scanner num1 = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter number:");
    String number1 = num1.nextLine();
    char [] numeral1 = number1.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < numeral1.length; x++) 
    System.out.print(numeral1 [x] + " ");
    num1.close();   
}
Console:
4485455
4 4 8 5 4 5 5 
Enter number:
548452
5 4 8 4 5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивная реализация:

```
public class Task {
  private int number;
  public Task(int number) {this.number = number;}
  public void printSpaced() {spaced(number);}

  private void spaced(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {System.out.print("-");spaced(-number);return;} // Support negative
    if (number >= 10) spaced(number/10);
    System.out.print(number%10 + " ");
  }
}
```